# Kernel tuning for service terminating millions of TCP connections

Tags: linux-kernel, netty

I just got up and running a service that at its peak needs to handle simultaneous TCP connections in the tens of millions. It's currently running without much tuning by just scaling up to a large number of hosts. The software itself is written in Netty and doesn't do much except translating data frames coming over WebSocket pipes into Kafka events.

My current goal is to be able to pack as many connections on a single machine as possible. I've currently settled for EC2 `r6i.2xlarge` instances which have 8 CPUs and 64GB of memory and I'm looking for some advice on kernel network stack and Netty tuning.

Some stats on WebSocket traffic patterns:

1. Each client sends a WebSocket data frame about once per 10 seconds.
2. Data frames are less than 32KB in size and most are less than 4KB.
3. We can have sudden bursts of a few million connections in a matter of seconds (various competitions/events).
4. Many connections are quite short and by far the most common data is actually a TCP accept followed by a login data frame followed by a connection close a few tens of seconds later.

From the above we see that the bitrate per TCP connection is less than 1KB/s and the connections are mostly idle. However, on the backend side we push events to Kafka in batches, so those are a much smaller number of sockets pushing lots of data each.

I've currently increased the `ulimit` and `tcp_max_orphans` flags to about 10 million each, since I assumed that both of these would be an issue.

Anyone familiar with the TCP/IP stack internals that would have some advice on what the most important tunables to look into would be?

My own starting point would be to limit the amount of memory that each socket uses as well as increase the amount of memory available to the TCP/IP stack. However, the math here is not very clear from the docs, i.e. how the different flags relate, since I don't know exactly how much memory a single TCP connection consumes inside the kernel.

Some concrete questions:

1. What options to use in Netty for these frontend WebSocket TCP connections given the traffic patterns described?
2. How to minimize the amount of memory used per socket in the kernel as well as how to calculate/set kernel memory limits from there?
3. Anything else worth looking into?